# How to copy graphs to a document using google script

Tags: graph, google-apps-script, document, spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet with processed data nice graphs that can be updated with different source data.

I have a script that can create a google document from a template and populate it with data (with search and replace).

However, I like to add the graphs from the google spreadsheet to the google document.

I've been googling a lot, but can't find a script that I can use/modify to pull of this thing.

A basic start would be highly appreciated.

***Update:***
I've made some progress

```
  function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var Grafieken = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(anID);
  var DBody = targetDoc.getBody();
  for (var i in Grafieken) {
    var Grafiek = Grafieken[i];
    var plaatje = DBody.appendImage(Grafiek);
  }
```

However I encountered two issues:
- most importantly, the graphs do not look like in the spreadsheet
- not all the graphs are added (e.g. mixed diagrams are skipped)

***UPDATE2***
This almost works, I need to know which graph is which.

```
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var Grafieken = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(DOC_id);
  var DBody = targetDoc.getBody();
  var Grafiek;
  for (var i in Grafieken)
    Grafiek = Grafieken[i];
    var locatie =  DBody.findText('%Grafiek'+i+'%').getElement().getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(Grafiek);

  }
}
```

Comment: I made some progress:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost done:

```
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var Grafieken = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(DOC_id);
  var DBody = targetDoc.getBody();
  var Grafiek;
  for (var i in Grafieken)
    Grafiek = Grafieken[i];
    var locatie =  DBody.findText('%Grafiek'+i+'%').getElement().getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(Grafiek);

  }
}
```